# Two-way binding doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli, two-way-binding

I'm trying to learn Angular and Angular-CLI. So I created a project with Angular-CLI, which from the beginning seems to run just fine. Now for testing I changed app.component.html file to the following:

```
<h1>Input your name:</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<p>Your input: {{ name }}</p>
```

and my app.component.ts accordingly:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'input'.

At this point for some reason nothing renders on the page. I tried to change the app.component.html to this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
...
```

Now the page renders correctly, I do see the input box, but as I type I don't see the two-way binding, I don't see the output in my `<p>` element.

Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="name"` should work. Are you getting any error in browser console? Did you import `FormsModule` in your `@NgModule`?

Comment: @yurzui Yes, there is: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<h1>Input your name:</h1>
<input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="name">
<p>Your input: {{ name }}</p>`

Comment: Then see @sachilaranawaka answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to import `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts` & your issue will get resolved. Something like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue! Guess I have a very steep learning curve ahead of me... Thank you very much! Will be able to accept the answer in a few minutes.