# how to assign values in model, retrieved from json response from subscribe in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am getting proper json response from the server from subscribe, but not able to assign the values to the form text fields. Please look into below code.

HTML piece of code:-

```
    <form class="inline-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="updateCompanyDettails(company)" #companyDetailsOverlayForm="ngForm">
                                    {{diagnostic}} 
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <h1 class="page-header">Company Detail</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for=" ct_company_id">Company ID</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                    <input [(ngModel)]="company.ct_company_id" id="ct_company_id" name="ct_company_id" #company.ct_company_id="ngModel" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+"
                                                      type="text" class="form-control" required>
                                                </div>
                                                {{company.ct_company_id}}
                                            </div>
```

This is Component code:-

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { ICTCompanyDetails } from './companydetails';
        import { CompanyDetailsService } from './companydetailsservice';
        import { CompanyDetailsComponent } from './companydetails.component';
        import { PaginationService } from './commonpagination';

        @Component({
            selector: 'company-popup',
            templateUrl: 'companydetailsoverlay.html'
        })

        export class CompanyDetailsPopUp {

            private company: ICTCompanyDetails = {
                    ct_company_id: "",
                    ct_company_owner_name: "",
                    ct_company_name: "",
                    ct_company_address: "",
                    ct_company_country: "",
                    ct_company_state: "",
                    ct_company_town_n_city: "",
                    ct_company_postalcode: "",
                    ct_company_email_id: "",
                    ct_company_mobile_no: "",
                    ct_company_phone_no: "",
                    ct_company_gst_no: "",
                    ct_company_pan_no: "",
                    ct_company_website: "",
                    ct_company_sac_code: "",
                    ct_company_logo_name: "",

                    ct_company_digital_sign_stamp_name: "",
                    //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp: new File([], ""),
                    //  ct_company_digital_sign_stamp       :new Blob([], { type: '' }),
                    ct_company_term_condition: "",
                    ct_company_revoke: "",
                    ct_company_status: "",
                    ct_company_last_update_datetime: new Date(),
                    ct_company_last_update_ip: "",
                    ct_company_last_update_login_id: ""
                };

getCompanyDetails(company_id: string): void {
                    this.comDetailsService.getCompanyDetails(company_id).
                        subscribe(
                        company => { company = company;
                            //error => this.errorMessage = error,
                            this.company.ct_company_id = company[0]['ct_company_id'];
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(company));
                            console.log("this.company.ct_company_id : " + company[0]['ct_company_id']);
                        });
                        //this.company.ct_company_id = company[0]['ct_company_id'];        
                }
            }
```

Comment: Consider adding a code block for the component code to improve readability.

Comment: Where you call getCompanyDetails method? I assume that either in constructor or in ngOnInit()-method.

Comment: Just FYI you don't need to json convert json data for console. Console can handle json data.

Comment: yes getCompanyDetails method is called in services provider from there it is calling rest web services, Solution provided by you now i am able to assign values to the model, but my form text fields are still empty. They are not auto filled by their corresponding model values.

Comment: @Janne Harju  i am able to assign values to the model, but my form text fields are still empty. They are not getting filled by their corresponding model values.

Comment: Does this update? {{company.ct_company_id}}

Comment: Can you provide your app.module.ts? Just wondering do you get similar error like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251963

Comment: @Janne Harju Yes  {{company.ct_company_id}} is getting updated and I have already added FormsModule in my SidebarModule which is getting imported in app.module.ts

Comment: Does twoway binfing works if you set some initial value to here private company: ICTCompanyDetails = {
                    ct_company_id: "Init value",
...

Comment: If i am removing the inital values it is giving me the compilation error. anf if i am using <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="company==''">
                            <h1 class="page-header">Company Detail </h1>
                            <h2>{{company.ct_company_id}}</h2> 
                        </div> it is giving false

Comment: I mean that something different than empty string as initial value. Now there is just "" try to set "some value" to it. And other comment to your *ngIf test. Try just this *ngIf="company"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to convert response to interface like this?

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

this.comDetailsService.getCompanyDetails(company_id).
    subscribe( (company: Response) => 
       {
          let ct_company = company.json() as ICTCompanyDetails;
          this.company = ct_company;
          // or with your way only update spesific fields
          this.company.ct_company_id = ct_company.ct_company_id;

          // if returned data is really in list then 
          // let ct_company_list = company.json() as ICTCompanyDetails[];
          // this.company = ct_company_list[0];
          // ...
          // and return variable name should be companies if it is list. Just readability thing.
       }
```

Why there is that **#company.ct_company_id="ngModel"**
If you want't twoway binding then **[(ngModel)]="company.ct_company_id"** is enough.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="company.ct_company_id" id="ct_company_id" name="ct_company_id" #company.ct_company_id="ngModel" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+" type="text" class="form-control" required>
```